# Can a HDMI component break while all other graphics outputs work? 

Tags: hdmi

To give you context for this problem, I'm using an i3 (2.83GHz) in an HTPC and as of about a month and half ago, the HDMI output of the board no longer works. DVI and D-sub do however. I assumed a motherboard problem and sent it off to Gigabyte who promptly returned it to say it passed validation.

The Gigabyte rep/tech who emailed me a response on my ticket claims that since this can't be a motherboard issue, since the motherboard passed their tests, it must be a processor problem.

Anyone familiar with the Intel HD graphics hardware? Is it possible for the HDMI component of my CPU to NOT work but all other graphic output to work fine? Is this how Intel HD graphics even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possible. It's a separate port, so by definition, the port could break, but the other two ports still work.  The rep was probably thinking about the clock controller.  But those aren't likely to break.  The ports are more likely to go haywire and cause weird screen problems.